# Pandas regex: extract url information from column

Tags: python, pandas, string

```
import pandas as pd    

d = {"Device_Type" : ["AXO145","TRU151","ZOD231","YRT326","LWR245"],
 "Stat_Access_Link" : ["<url>https://xcd32112.smart_meter.com</url>",
                       "<url>http://tXh67.dia_meter.com</url>",
                       "<url>https://yT5495.smart_meter.com</url>",
                       "<url>https://ret323_TRu.crown.com</url>",
                       "<url>https://luwr3243.celcius.com</url>"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I have a dataframe like this and what I need to do is extract url information from tags using regex.
The output has to be like this:

| Device_Type | Stat_Access_Link |
| --- | --- |
| AXO145 | `xcd32112.smart_meter.com` |
| TRU151 | `tXh67.dia_meter.com` |
| ZOD231 | `yT5495.smart_meter.com` |
| YRT326 | `ret323_TRu.crown.com` |
| LWR245 | `luwr3243.celcius.com` |

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.extract` is what you need:

```
d = {"Device_Type" : ["AXO145","TRU151","ZOD231","YRT326","LWR245"],
 "Stat_Access_Link" : ["<url>https://xcd32112.smart_meter.com</url>",
                       "<url>http://tXh67.dia_meter.com</url>",
                       "<url>https://yT5495.smart_meter.com</url>",
                       "<url>https://ret323_TRu.crown.com</url>",
                       "<url>https://luwr3243.celcius.com</url>"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=://)(.*)(?=</url)")
df['Stat_Access_Link'] = df['Stat_Access_Link'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Device_Type          Stat_Access_Link
0      AXO145  xcd32112.smart_meter.com
1      TRU151       tXh67.dia_meter.com
2      ZOD231    yT5495.smart_meter.com
3      YRT326      ret323_TRu.crown.com
4      LWR245      luwr3243.celcius.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a regex?

If you always have `<url>...</url>`, use:

```
df['Stat_Access_Link'].str[5:-6]
```

else, you could use:

```
df['Stat_Access_Link'].str.extract(r'<url>(.*)</url>', expand=False)

# OR

df['Stat_Access_Link'].str.extract(r'<url>([^<>]*)</url>', expand=False)
```

output:

```
0    https://xcd32112.smart_meter.com
1          http://tXh67.dia_meter.com
2      https://yT5495.smart_meter.com
3        https://ret323_TRu.crown.com
4        https://luwr3243.celcius.com
Name: Stat_Access_Link, dtype: object
```

Comment: oh, again faster than me. should i delete my answer? it is nearly the same

Comment: @Rabinzel you don't need to delete it, yours was what I exactly needed thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should consider using the pandas solution `pd.DataFrame.str.extract` since it is built into pandas.

```py
reg=r'\/\/([\s\S]*)<'
df['matched'] = df['Stat_Access_Link'].str.extract(reg)
print(df)
```

Here are what the results look like:

|  | Device_Type | Stat_Access_Link | matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AXO145 | https://xcd32112.smart_meter.com | xcd32112.smart_meter.com |
| 1 | TRU151 | http://tXh67.dia_meter.com | tXh67.dia_meter.com |
| 2 | ZOD231 | https://yT5495.smart_meter.com | yT5495.smart_meter.com |
| 3 | YRT326 | https://ret323_TRu.crown.com | ret323_TRu.crown.com |
| 4 | LWR245 | https://luwr3243.celcius.com | luwr3243.celcius.com |

## Resources

1. pandas extract — https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html
2. test your regex — https://regex101.com/